# unable to parse my custom log in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

Here given below is my Service log I want to parse this log into logstash. please suggests some plugin or method to parse the log.

```
"msgs": [{
        "ts": "2017-07-17T12:22:00.2657422Z",
        "tid": 4,
        "eid": 1,
        "lvl": "Information",
        "cat": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost",
        "msg": {
            "cnt": "Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:20001/Processor text/xml; charset=utf-8 601",
            "Protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
            "Method": "POST",
            "ContentType": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
            "ContentLength": 601,
            "Scheme": "http",
            "Host": "localhost:20001",
            "PathBase": "",
            "Path": "/Processor",
            "QueryString": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "ts": "2017-07-17T12:22:00.4617773Z",
        "tid": 4,
        "lvl": "Information",
        "cat": "NCR.CP.Service.ServiceHostMiddleware",
        "msg": {
            "cnt": "REQ"
        },
        "data": {
            "Headers": {
                "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
                "Content-Length": "601",
                "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
                "Expect": "100-continue",
                "Host": "localhost:20001",
                "SOAPAction": "\"http://servereps.mtxeps.com/TransactionService/SendTransaction\""
            }
        }
    }]
```

please suggest me some the way to apply filter on this type of logs, so that i can take out fields from this logs and visualize in kibana.

i have heard of grok filter but what pattern i have to use here for the same.

Comment: What format is this source log? JSON as you pasted?

Comment: If the log you posted is the message you receive, you could just use the json codec/filter and then you would not need to parse the log.